# Strange behaivour of TypeScript when extending class with similar namespace structure

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, types

Recently I've been trying to create a type library for library written in JS. When I declared all namespaces, classes and interfaces, some classes started to give me an error `TS2417`. I checked if there was any problem with invalid overriding of methods or properties, but I couldn't find anything. After some time I've found that the problematic class had same name as one of the namespaces (for example class `A.B` and namespace `A.B`). But this didn't cause any trouble. The problem was that the parent class (of the problematic class) had, just as the problematic class, namespace which was named exactly the same and this namespace and the namespace of the problematic class had class, which was named exactly the same, but had different interface (it is very hard for me to describe the problem, so I [simulated here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA7KBbEBnADlMCCC8A3gFDzyRTrrwBCRxp8Avg2cmljgnSWWRVXgANeozItxrctEEBheCAAeAFxCJg1PADoeUlo3YZsuePN58B1Eeb7kA9onTKYAVzDK7MABSKAXEhcUACMQGABKMWZGFiYgA)).

So the question is, **what causes this problem?**

In this example the problematic class is `A.C`, but it has problems due to incompatible constructors of classes `A.C.X` and `A.B.X`.

```
declare namespace A {
  class B {

  }

  namespace B {
    class X {

    }
  }

  class C extends A.B {

  }

  namespace C {
    class X {
      constructor(x: number)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What, specifically, is the question here? Is it "why is this happening?" If so, it's because `A.C` is declared as `extends A.B` but it is not assignable to `A.B`.  That is, you should be able to write `const c: typeof A.B = A.C` and then `new c.X()` with no problem, but `A.C.X`'s constructor requires a `number` argument.  So you risk runtime errors like [this](//tsplay.dev/WzLleN).  Note that in this example I've replaced all the declaration merging with concrete implementations, but it's the exact same issue. If this makes sense I can write up an answer.  If I'm missing something let me know.

Comment: @jcalz I am sorry about forgetting to put the specific question, but you were right. I just wanted to know, why this was happening and now I understand, so thank you!

Comment: Okay, I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In the following I will dispense with the namespace `A`)

With the exception of the [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures), the `static` side of a `class` is checked for [substitutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitutability) the same way that the instance side is; so if you have `class X { static prop: string = "" }`, then you can't have `class Y extends X { static prop: number = 2}`.  When you say `class Y extends X` you are declaring that, among other things, `Y.prop` is assignable to `X.prop`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#4628](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4628) for more information.  Not everyone likes this constraint, but it's there.

---

That means the following should work with no error:

```
const X: typeof B.X = C.X; // should be okay
new X(); // should be okay
```

But a concrete implementation of your classes could easily lead to a runtime error:

```
class B {
  static X = class { }
}

class C extends B {
  static X = class {
    constructor(x: number) {
      x.toFixed();
    }
  }
}
```

Here, `C.X` is a class constructor which requires a `number` input.  But `B.X` is a class constructor which does not require any input at all.  And if you treat the former as if it were the latter, than at runtime you will be calling the `toFixed()` method on `undefined`.  Oops.

And that's why `class C extends B` generates a compiler error; to protect you against substitutability issues arising from the static side of a class.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBC0G8BQ1oQC5nQS2NAGtALzSiQwLQC+SNSZU0AwtAKYAe6rAdgCYzxkqDFlwFipcIyGpSAe24YATgFdg6OUoAU7AFzRuKgLYAjVkoCUiFLNTsAdBoBi2dq15aLAbhuoaf2iQkblYAd2Z7fC0ARgAmAGZvaAB6ZOg5AGswAE8g4AUMAn10bIAHVjkAMzhIiSZIrxS00LkVEF5oM3Ss3JDwqKTU6FVuHCNWNiUlTQAacWwYFT5WSuwQ3iA)